# Using TensorFlow in IDE on Windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pycharm

I have used the Docker installation as suggested at https://bishnusarker.wordpress.com/2015/11/11/how-to-install-google-tensorflow-in-your-windows-machine-using-docker-image/ to run TensorFlow on my Windows 7 machine. I have it up and running on the docker terminal. I would like to know how to import the TensorFlow library from the PyCharm IDE.

Comment: Since you are using Docker but mention Windows as the IDE (PyCharm), is PyCharm running on Linux in Docker, or is PyCharm installed on Windows and you want to use it from within Windows? I am also adding the PyCharm tag and you should change the tag from Windows to Linux if PyCharm is running on Linux.

Comment: I spent ages trying to get similar stuff to work, eventually I just went a head and installed Linux mint on my machine. I would strongly recommend that. (also mint is really good)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am currently struggling with a similar issue, I came across your question. You can run PyCharm on your Windows machine and configure a remote interpreter to mount your python code to the docker image, in which your libraries reside and run it there as described here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/12/using-docker-in-pycharm/
For tensorflow in particular, this might be interesting as well: http://killianlevacher.github.io/blog/posts/post-2016-07-22/post.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make it work. Your tensorflow installation is inside the docker container, while PyCharm running on Windows searches for your available Python libraries in Windows; it has no access to docker.

You could, instead, try to install and run PyCharm in docker as well (I'm not sure if it is viable though).